# Managed Azure Kubernetes connection error

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-container-service

The **error** I am getting after running **kubectl cluster-info**

Kubernetes master is running at https://xxx-xxx-aks-yyyy.hcp.westeurope.azmk8s.io:443

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
**Unable to connect to the server: net/http: TLS handshake timeout**
Rifats-MacBook-Pro:~ rifaterdemsahin$ kubectl cluster-info

Answer (score 1):

There is some issue on Azure Server. Please refer to this similar [issue](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/112).

I suggest you could try again, if it still does not work, you could open a ticket or give feedback to Azure.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this one for me was to scale the nodes in my Cluster from the Azure Kubernetes service blade web console (NOT your local terminal since you can't connect with kubectl).

After scaling up by one (and back down to save costs) I am back working again.

## Workaround / Solution

1. Log into the Azure Console — Kubernetes Service blade.
2. Scale your cluster up by 1 node.
3. Wait for scale to complete and attempt to connect (you should be able to).
4. Scale your cluster back down to the normal size to avoid cost increases.

Total time it took me ~2 mins.

### More Background Info on the Issue

Added this to the full ticket description write up that I posted over here (if you want more info have a read):

['Unable to connect Net/http: TLS handshake timeout' — Why can't Kubectl connect to Azure AKS server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50726534/unable-to-connect-net-http-tls-handshake-timeout-why-cant-kubectl-connect)